# Do I need to wait for 100% resync?

Tags: windows-10, software-raid, raid-1

I have set up a mirrored partition in Windows 10. Today I noticed a lot of disk activity in task manager for no apparent reason. Looking up the disk management, I see that it is resynchng.

[image: Windows 10 mirror in resynching state]

In task manager, I also see that the disks are busy with ~100MB/s. So the complete process will take about 11 hours for the 4TB disk.

Can I safely shut down my computer and will it continue the process after next boot? Or will it restart from the beginning and it's better to leave the PC on?

Comment: I would leave it on because software RAID usually has to mark the mirrors OK before shutting down the system. Do you know why the system decided to resync? Did the system make an uncontrolled shutdown?

Comment: I can't remember an uncontrolled shutdown. And I also find it frustrating that the system did not inform me that a resync is neccesary. I thought it would tell me that my data is 50% lost and how to continue

Comment: Does an answer depend on knowing why Windows does the resync?

Comment: Yes, that would be useful. But general knowledge about software RAID or mirroring may help you judge the situation. In this case I would leave the process running until the mirror is OK. Then test with a normal reboot and see if the mirror stays OK. Finally I would try an uncontrolled shutdown like powering of the system and see how the system handles that situation. But my experience with mirrors is that they require a full resync after a none controlled shutdown. For that reason mirroring would not be my choice with 4TB disks.

Comment: Are you sure on this? It would seem like _really_ bad design on a solved problem -Linux mdadm;siftware RAID dies not suffer from this.

Comment: I just tested this with my Windows 10 Software Raid 1 Mirror and indeed the resynching progress started over from 0% after rebooting (was >50% before reboot).